# Password reset – have a pop-up that confirms when a password is reset

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I was assigned to do this task. My page contain two textboxes (for a new password and confirmation) and a button to save data. In the button-click event I first validate if the two textboxes are empty or there is a mismatch or the entered value doesn't follow the rules. After the user enters a correct password in the two textboxes and clicks save, at that time a pop-up will show a message "confirm password change". Only after clicking 'OK',the data will be saved to the database. When the user clicks cancel data is not saved and return false.

Here i write my code:

```
protected void btnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtNewPassword.Text.Trim().Length <= 0)
    {
    }

    if (txtConfirmNewPassword.Text.Trim().Length <= 0)
    {
    }

    if (txtNewPassword.Text.Trim() != txtConfirmNewPassword.Text.Trim())
    {
    }
    else
    {
        //correct format and save the values.here i want to see a popup msg first and then click ok save values,otherwise exit..
    }
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible through server code alone unless you add an intermediate step after the user fills the new password field.

The best way to do this is validate the password field on the client using javascript or jQuery and display a confirm dialog if txtNewPassword == txtConfirmNewPassword and then call the server to save the change.

Comment: `What you're trying to do isn't possible through server code alone`: that's not true.  The post processing for the page can render a 'pop-up' box in the form of a `div`.  AJAX could even be implemented to do this.

Comment: it is entirely true through server code alone unless you add client code no matter what way you add it

Comment: Because of the very nature of ASP.NET, persistence is granted through a `VIEWSTATE` hidden element on the page.  Variables are passed backwards and forwards.  When the page is posted to the server the page can be re-rendered from what it was based on its `VIEWSTATE`.  You can then change existing server side objects on the page to be displayed or hidden as required. I do this all the time on my pages.

Comment: congratulations, however you are still wrong and you have quoted only part of my sentence, go away now

Comment: Westie, I'm not sure how you can start out by disagreeing that it can't be done with server code alone, and then immediately switch into talking about divs (client-side!) and ajax (client-side!). You're effectively agreeing with Ted without even realising.

Comment: By defining a div that operates server side you can control its properties server side using ASP.NET.  The fact that the div is HTML is irrelevant really - it's still a server side operation. `<div id="my_id" runat="server" class="hidden">...</div>`. Do I need to continue?  What isn't server side about that control?  Further edit: If you wish to do it a slightly different way you could use a a `Panel` control if that makes you feel more ... comfortable.

Comment: ...However I will concede the AJAX bit.

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code in java script for client side validation call the function in onclientclick event

```
function validate() {

               if (document.getElementById("<%=txtNewPassword.ClientID%>").value == 0) {
                    alert("Please Enter New Password.");
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtNewPassword.ClientID%>").focus();
                    return false;
                }
              if (document.getElementById("<%=txtConfirmPassword.ClientID%>").value == 0) {
                    alert("Please Enter Confirm Password.");
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtConfirmPassword.ClientID%>").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("<%=txtNewPassword.ClientID%>").value != document.getElementById("<%=txtConfirmPassword.ClientID%>").value) {
                    alert("Provided Confirmation Password is wrong.");
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtConfirmPassword.ClientID%>").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                    alert("do you want to save password");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to pop up any ifram or page you want

- you need to creat confirm.aspx to confirm password change
- to open confirm.aspx from code behind use this code

  ```
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "key", "window.onload=function(){parent.location.href = 'confirm.aspx';}", true);
  ```